# Audio pause/play with JS variable (ubernewb)

Tags: javascript, html, variables, audio

I'm working on a simple project that includes a media (mp3) player in the sidebar. I can get the play/pause button to visually switch and I can turn off the audio by assigning a href to another image however when trying to get the swapped image to pause audio I just can't seem to figure it out, here's my code..

EDIT: deleted shotty code

EDIT: Figured out three ways to do this, the two kind people below posted great ways but I also figured out how to crudely do this via jquery.

```
$('#left-05-pause_').click(function(){
    $('#left-05-pause_').hide();
    $('#left-05-play_').show();
    }); 

$('#left-06-audio_').click(function(){
    audio.volume = 1;
    $('#left-06-audio_').hide();
    $('#left-06-mute_').show();
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mitch, I have three points for you:

- there's no need to wrap `<a>` around `<img>`
- for performance avoid overuse of selecting elements (like getElementById), because once you've selected a link to the element put it into a variable and use again to access the same element
- use native info about element's state (for `<audio>` in this example) - explore its properties

All in all just try next sample (file names have been changed for clarity):

```
<body>
  <audio id="audioId">
    <source src="song.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
  </audio>
  <img id="imageId" src="play.png" onclick="toggle()" />
  <script>
    var audio = document.getElementById( 'audioId' )
      , image = document.getElementById( 'imageId' )

    function toggle()
    {
      if ( audio.paused )
      {
        image.src = 'pause.png'
        audio.play()
      }
      else
      {
        image.src = 'play.png'
        audio.pause()
      }
    }
  </script>  
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<a href="#">
<img src="http://royaltrax.com/aadev/images/left/images/left_05.png" id="imgPauseChange" onclick="changeImage()">
</a>
<script language="javascript">
    function changeImage() {

        if (document.getElementById("imgPauseChange").src == "http://royaltrax.com/aadev/images/left/images/left_05.png")
        {
            document.getElementById("aud").play();
            document.getElementById("imgPauseChange").src = "http://royaltrax.com/aadev/images/left/images/left_05-pause.png";

         }
        else 
        {
            document.getElementById("aud").pause();
            document.getElementById("imgPauseChange").src = "http://royaltrax.com/aadev/images/left/images/left_05.png";
        }
    }
</script>
```